Firebase Function onFlow Throws ZodError: invalid_type When Using Input Schema Validation
I'm working with Firebase Cloud Functions and the @genkit-ai library to create a flow using onFlow. I've defined a simple flow called menuSuggestionFlow, where I validate the input using a Zod schema. However, when I try to invoke this flow, I receive a ZodError indicating that the input is undefined, even though I believe I'm sending the correct data structure.
import { z } from '@genkit-ai/core/schema';
import { onFlow, noAuth } from '@genkit-ai/firebase/functions';

// Define the schema
export const ChatSessionInputSchema = z.object({
  question: z.string(),
});

export const menuSuggestionFlow = onFlow(
  {
    name: "menuSuggestionFlow",
    inputSchema: ChatSessionInputSchema, // Apply the schema here
    authPolicy: noAuth(),
  },
  async (subject) => {
    console.log(`Validated subject: ${JSON.stringify(subject)}`);

    if (!subject || !subject.question) {
      throw new Error("The 'question' field is required.");
    }

    const answer = `This is the answer to your question: ${subject.question}`;
    return { answer };
  }
);

menuSuggestionFlow({ data: { question: "What is the menu suggestion for today?" } })
menuSuggestionFlow( { question: "What is the menu suggestion for today?" } )

Your code seems to be correct, so I assume there might be something wrong with how you're calling the flow.
In my environment, your code is working for both the Dev UI and curl POST.

Dev UI (run genkit start -o)



curl

$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"data": {"question": "What is the menu suggestion for today?"}}' http://[your_firebase_function_url]/menuSuggestionFlow
{"result":{"answer":"This is the answer to your question: What is the menu suggestion for today?"}}

